# pub get failed command: "C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart __deprecated_pub --color --directory ..\..\src\flutter\ ........" exit code: 69

Tags: flutter

the last time when I tried to create a new flutter project, that problem appear to me

```
The semaphore timeout period has expired.
pub get failed
command: "C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart __deprecated_pub --directory packages\flutter_tools get --example"
pub env: {
  "FLUTTER_ROOT": "C:\src\flutter",
  "PUB_ENVIRONMENT": "flutter_cli:get",
  "PUB_CACHE": "C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache",
}
exit code: 69

#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
#1      _DefaultPub._runWithStdioInherited (package:flutter_tools/src/dart/pub.dart:468:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      _DefaultPub.get (package:flutter_tools/src/dart/pub.dart:346:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      PubDependencies.update (package:flutter_tools/src/flutter_cache.dart:125:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      Cache.updateAll (package:flutter_tools/src/cache.dart:677:9)
```

I tried to fix it by deleting cash from flutter-sdk and running `flutter pub cache repair` on cmd but it didn't work then I delete dart and flutter sdk and download them again and put them paths in system environment and typed `flutter doctor` and this error still appear to me

Comment: I found the solution by Chat GPT

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and i solved it by running `flutter clean` , `flutter pub upgrade`, then `flutter pub get`

Answer (score 3):

you can solve this running below commands. Not all the time chatgpt gives you rigth answer.

1. **flutter clean**
2. **flutter pub upgrade**
3. **flutter pub get**

Answer (score 1):

Delete your .pub-cache folder:

"PUB_CACHE": "C:\Users\Manish\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache",

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWhAf.png)

Comment: Deleted Cache contents except the Cache folder. It worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it by adding sdk for the project by click :
alt + ctrl + shift + windows at same time and adding your bath of sdk
Greetings Mr_fostoq

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by Chat GPT.

just disable all antivirus programs and I think I can disable protection on flutter SDK after that.

By the way, now I'm so satisfied after one week can't use flutter

Comment: I'm surprised that it is working!

Answer (score 0):

The error `"The semaphore timeout period has expired"` usually occurs on network timeouts as mentioned in this [thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/107307#issuecomment-1179922259). Try using other networks or check if there's anything that blocks the Flutter SDK causing `pub get` to fail.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem trying to run my app on ios

and my pubspec.yaml depends on another project on my windows pc so i used to import the project like this

- Windows

  ```
     theAppName:
         path: D:/projects/theAppName
  ```

but I realised that the path on macOS is just different

- MacOs

  ```
     otherProjectName:
         path: /Users/rageh/Developer/apps/theAppName
  ```

so, fixing the path fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

Delete '**pubspec.lock**' file.
Then, run **flutter pub get**.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using a wrong reference when importing the project directly from Github:

```
  lib_x:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/zxcv/lib_x
      ref: master <------- I was trying to use master
```

```
  lib_x:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/zxcv/lib_x
      ref: main <------- The correct branch was main
```

Answer (score 0):

In Flutter project, I Also faced with this issue. I found two way to solve this.

1st Option.

- `flutter --version`

[Ex:- Tools • Dart **2.18.4** • DevTools 2.15.0]

check your environment sdk version in pubspec.ymal
[Ex:-environment:
sdk: '>=**2.18.6** <3.0.0' ]

If computer Dart version is less than your project Dart sdk version
reduce project environment sdk version less than computer Dart sdk version.

[Ex:-environment:
sdk: '>=**2.18.3** <3.0.0']

- `flutter clean`
- `flutter pub get`
- `flutter run`

*** This is a easy way, but please check Dart sdk version with other packages ***

2nd Option.

- `flutter clean`
- `flutter pub upgrade`
- `flutter pub get`

There has special code for MAC users

*`rm -Rf ios/Pods`

*`rm -Rf ios/.symlinks`

*`rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework`

*`rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec`

*`flutter pub get`

*`cd ios`

*`pod install`

*`arch -x86_64 pod install`  //(On an M1 mac use => arch -x86_64 pod install)

*`cd ..`

*`flutter run`

Answer (score 0):

```
Connection closed before full header was received
pub get failed
command: "/Users/moweb/Desktop/Hardik/flutter-3.7.10/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart __deprecated_pub --color --directory . get --example"
pub env: {
  "FLUTTER_ROOT": "/Users/moweb/Desktop/Hardik/flutter-3.7.10",
  "PUB_ENVIRONMENT": "flutter_cli:get",
  "PUB_CACHE": "/Users/moweb/.pub-cache",
}
exit code: 69
```

**Check your internet connection first. Because of low internet speed this is happened.**

- Then, run the command :

  - **flutter clean**
  - **flutter pub get**

Answer (score 0):

The reason I got this error was because I set it to flutter channel stable, when I changed my own problem to flutter channel master, the problem was solved.

-> flutter channel master
-> flutter pub get